# Angular Directive param value array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I use an array which is given as an attribute of a directive in the linker of the directive

```
[
{
    "state": "bootstrap.formwizard.ethernet",
    "placeHolder": "lNetworkConfWizardMenu",
    "stepNumber": 1,
    "next": "bootstrap.formwizard.datetime"
},
{
    "state": "bootstrap.formwizard.datetime",
    "placeHolder": "lDateSetWizardMenu",
    "previous": "bootstrap.formwizard.ethernet",
    "stepNumber": 2,
    "next": "bootstrap.formwizard.countrysetting"
},
]
```

Template

```
<formprogressbar steps="wizardSteps"  />
```

Directive

```
angular.module('smaModules.formProgressbar', [])

.directive('formprogressbar', function ($log) {

    function linker(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope);
        test = attrs.steps[0]
        console.log(test);
    }


    return {
        restrict: 'E',
         scope: { 
             steps: '=' 
        },
        template: 'Steps: {{ steps[0] }}',
        link: linker
    };
});
```

In the template I have access but not in the linker function. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You want to access the steps off of your scope for it to be the same as in your template.  Also you should declare your variable for best practice.

```
.directive('formprogressbar', function ($log, $filter) {

    function linker(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope);
        var test = scope.steps[0];
        console.log(test);
    }


    return {
        restrict: 'E',
         scope: { 
             steps: '=' 
        },
        template: 'Steps: {{ steps[0] }}',
        link: linker
    };
});
```

`attrs.steps[0]` was probably giving you the result of `'w'`, this is because `attrs.steps` is the string `"wizardSteps"`, the first index of the string being `'w'`.